# Perform transformations according to x and y axis

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm developing a drawing app whereby users can draw a polygon of maximum 9 sides by clicking on a button and afterwards perform transformations to the shape drawn but i can't get the transformations to map correctly to x and y axis (depending on the user's choice of axis).
Here's my codes for the rotation function:

```
function rotate()
{
    polygonSides = document.getElementById("polygonSide").value;
    var coordinates = [],
    radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((50), 2) + Math.pow((50), 2)),
    index = 0;
    var angle = 0 * (Math.PI / 180);

    for (index = 0; index < polygonSides; index++) {
        coordinates.push({x: -200 + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: -100 - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
        angle += (2 * Math.PI) / polygonSides;
    }

    var rad = prompt("Enter angle in radians: ","");
    var rad = prompt("Enter x or y axis: ","x or y"); //how to use this to map?

    context.translate(canvas.width / 5, canvas.height / 5); //not working with value 2


    context.rotate(Math.PI / rad);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
    for (index = 1; index < polygonSides; index++) {
        context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
    }

    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;

}
```

The axis is (0,0) in the center of the canvas. When i rotate with radian 4 i get this as output:
[image]

How can i modify my codes to accomodate rotation based on x or y axis?

Comment: you can use `CSS3 transform Property`.     transform: rotateX(angle) // Defines a 3D rotation along the X-axis

Comment: Should i put the css as inline in my canvas?

Comment: Using styling inline and using code for animation is not a good practice. Good practice to use styling from class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery to apply css.
example

```
var $canvas = $("#bkgimg");
rotate(45);

    function rotate(degree) {
  // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
       $canvas.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotateX(' + degree + 'deg)'});
  // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
       $canvas.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotateX(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
div {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

if you are using css3 then you can go for translateX and translateY